# Compare Substring from 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I Try to run a Query That compares if a Substring from a Column exists in another column:

Table "Tracker" contains a column "Urls" with tracking domains.
Table "Crawl" Contains a column "TargetUrl" with urls.

I want to check if a tracking domain is present in TargetUrl and if so join them so I have all data from both tables together.

Tables look roughly like this:

Tracker Table

```
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------------------------+
| ID | Category      | Entity         |Urls                           |
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | Sessionreplay | Hotjar         | hotjar.com                    |
|  2 | Analytics     | Sometool       | somesite.com                  |
|  3 | Adverts       | Someothertool  | someothersite.com             |
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------------------------+
```

Crawl Table

```
+----+---------------+---------+------+-------------------------------+
| ID | Mainpage      | Some Data      |TargetUrl                      |
+----+---------------+---------+------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | xyz.com       | 111111         | https://script.hotjar.com/1232|
|  2 | yzx.com       | 22222222       | https://somesite.com/423423   |
|  3 | zxy.com       | 3333333333333  | notrackingscript.com          | 
+----+---------------+----------------+-------------------------------+
```

This is how far I got

```
SELECT * FROM Crawl WHERE Crawl.TargetUrl like '%hotjar.com%'
```

Returns everything from Table Crawl where "hotjar.com" is present in the column TargetUrl.

Could anyone of you SQL Gurus help a newbie out with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables with the LIKE operator:

```
select *
from crawl c inner join tracker t
on c.targeturl like '%' || t.urls || '%'
```

this will return all the columns from both tables. 
You can change that by choosing columns like:

```
select t.id, t.category, c.mainpage, ...
```

The condition for the join is that the `column tracker.urls` is contained inside the column `crawl.targeturl`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked flawlessly!